# Spring Boot web application doesn't serve standard endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with a Spring Boot Application that is supposed to run from command line and at the same time serve some metrics from the standard **/metrics** endpoint. When I just created the application all the metrics were served correctly, but at some point I seem to have "broken" something and my application stopped serving from default endpoints. I can't just revert to the initial state because there's a lot of code already and I don't want to lose version control history. Maybe someone could point at what I am doing wrong?

I don't override dispatcher servlet and don't add any custom filters.

Spring Boot version 1.3.7.

**Error when accessing /metrics or any other default endpoint**:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Oct 03 17:53:12 PDT 2016 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

**Application file:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Main runner file:**

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        // shortened ...
    }
}
```

**POM file fragment:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- spring boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

**Debug output shows that the filters are created:**

```
2016-10-03 17:26:14.461 DEBUG 85880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.class]
2016-10-03 17:26:14.720 DEBUG 85880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'metricFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class]
```

I created a sample clean application to compare and there are lines in output that I don't have in my app:

```
2016-10-03 18:06:48.075 DEBUG 86858 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : 2 request handler methods found on class org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint: {public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)={[/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}, public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()={[],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}}
2016-10-03 18:06:48.076  INFO 86858 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2016-10-03 18:06:48.076  INFO 86858 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

So, the filters/servlet seem to be created but not mapped in my app.
What am I possibly missing here?

Comment: A 404 is resource is not found - so what web resource are available and what resource are you trying to get.  The configuration is in `ApplicationProperties.class` so how about showing this code?

Comment: @ScaryWombat ApplicationProperties.class is a simple POJO to get some text properties from the application startup parameters. It does not affect the web configuration in any way. I am trying to access the /metrics endpoint, as stated in the question, and that is when I get a 404. Why are you minusing the question?

Comment: `minusing` - wow I learnt a new word.  Actually I am trying to help you.  I am trying to ascertain what code you have that actually maps to `metrics` and I can not see any.

Comment: BTW If you are using Eclipse and/or SVN then maybe you can do a `compare` with previous version.

Comment: @ScaryWombat OK, well, downvoted if that makes it better. I just created a verb from "minus". I use git and Intellij Idea and of course I could do compare and partial revert-and-restore step by step if it was easy. But it's not just one version. The endpoints haven't been used for more than a week and in that time, a whole lot of commits had been made. I could try to create a new app and move all the code to it but then I'd lose pretty much all history.

Comment: Have you considered that I am not the downvoter?  Anyway, what I am trying to see is where the `metrics` path/endpoint is defined.  Without that how does you app suppose to work (maybe my lack of understanding).  As for `minusing` see http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=minusing

Comment: @ScaryWombat and I do not have any code that maps to /metrics. In fact, I am not supposed to! That is one of the endpoints that are available out of the box with Spring Boot web apps. With my sample apps, it works like a charm, but obviously with this app, something has been broken and I can't pinpoint what and when.

Comment: @ScaryWombat if you're not the downvoter then I can only apologise for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @ScaryWombat never knew that "minusing" was actually a word and in urban dictionary. =) I thought I just invented it.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding `/metrics` is actually a built-in endpoint (now I see).  According to this page http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html  the endpoint is be auto-enabled unless overriden in application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was stupid. Could say it twice.
So, after all, the problem was my bad memory. I actually was overriding application properties like this:

```
management.contextPath=/services/admin
```

Guess what, my /metrics was there all the time. It was just under /services/admin/metrics, which I completely forgot to have overridden. Duh.